# Firebase onDisconnect not deleting user name on disconnection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Perhaps I am mis-using onDisonnect(), but I looked at the example code on the firebase.blog and am doing my best.

When a user submits a user name, I call the code below, which adds the username to a firebase db. Then on disconnection, I want the username to be deleted from the db. This would mean that the db would only show users that are connected to the app at that moment in time.

I am doing it this way so I can then call the data and then map through the array to display currently logged-in users.

I have made two attempts in deleting the name, which you can see in the code below under `con.onDisconnect().remove();`, neither of which work the way I need. That said, if I log in once again from the same computer, the first user name replaces the second user name!

Here is my code

```
setName = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let name = this.state.name;
    let connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
    connectedRef.on('value', function (snap) {
      if (snap.val() === true) {
        // Connected
        let con = myConnectionsRef.push();
        myConnectionsRef.set({
          name
        })
        // On disconnect 
        con.onDisconnect().remove();

        myConnectionsRef.orderByChild('name').equalTo(name).once('child_added', function (snapshot) {
          snapshot.ref.remove();

        // var nameRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+name);
        // nameRef.remove()
        })
      }
    });
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to use onDisconnect? From the example on the fb forum, it isn't clear where I would put that block of code, hence why I am attempting to do it this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what is your goal, you **don't** need to do

```
myConnectionsRef.orderByChild('name').equalTo(name).once('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.ref.remove();

// var nameRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+name);
// nameRef.remove()
})
```

as the [`onDisconnect().remove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect.html#remove) call will take care of that.

Also, as explained in the blog [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) you refer to (as well as shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities)):

> The `onDisconnect()` call shall be **before** the call to `set()` itself. This is to
>   avoid a race condition where you set the user's presence to true and
>   the client disconnects before the `onDisconnect()` operation takes
>   effect, leaving a ghost user.

---

So the following code should do the trick:

```
setName = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let name = this.state.name;

    const connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');

    const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');

    connectedRef.on('value', function (snap) {
      if (snap.val() === true) {
        // Connected
        const con = usersRef.child(name);  //Here we define a Reference

        // When I disconnect, remove the data at the Database location corresponding to the Reference defined above 
        con.onDisconnect().remove();

       // Add this name to the list of users
        con.set(true);   //Here we write data (true) to the Database location corresponding to the Reference defined above 
      }
    });
```

The users node will display the list of connected users by name, as follows:

```
- users
   - James: true
   - Renaud: true
```

Comment: Okay, that's great! I was getting close but you've just nailed it. Thank you.